# Trouble with running a shell script via a Cronjob on an EC2 Instance

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I am trying to to run a cronjob of a script on an EC2 Instance but it's simply not working
The way I am running it right now is

```
15 * * * * root /home/ec2-user s3_upload.sh TestBucket
```

I wrote this when I did crontab -e

Right now I am in this directory /home/ec2-user/ so I don't know if maybe that has something to do with why it's not running.

I just don't understand this whole cron thing and how permissions work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try looking at the man pages: `man crontab`, `man cron`

Comment: syntax is not right. What is your intention. cd to that directory and execute the .sh file?

Comment: yes I would like to cd to that directory and execute the s3_upload.sh script.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't specify a username in a user's crontab, only in `/etc/crontab`.
2. You can't specify a directory in any form of crontab. To change directory, use cd.
3. The environment is not the same. If you e.g. set PATH in `.bashrc`, these will not be automatically included, so it's safest to use full paths.

As root (assuming you want to run this as root and not ec2-user or something), run `crontab -e` and add

```
15 * * * * cd /home/ec2-user && /full/path/to/s3_upload.sh TestBucket
```

Make sure you can copy-paste the command in a root terminal and get it working, and read root's mail afterwards to see the command's output with possible error messages. If it still doesn't work, make sure you have these errors available.

Comment: I tried running this and it still didn't work, I don't think I am the root, how would I run this if I am not the root?

Comment: Sorry to keep spamming but I am a total noob, so this script also interacts with files in /home/ec2-user and other directories, all I know is that when I run it from inside /home/ec2-user, the script works but the cron job does not. Thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: Before running the s3_upload.sh command, type `whoami` to see which user you're running as. Then `crontab -e` and add this (it will be added to the current user's crontab). You can probably check your user's mail with `mail` to see error messages once it's run.